# Modify Laravel built-in Auth for users

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authentication

I am using Laravel built-in Authentication for users which I run from the terminal `php artisan make:auth`

It has one table in the database, `users` table and has an `isAdmin` column, so I am assuming it has two roles an `admin` and `not_amin` account.

Now, what I want is to modify this built-in functionality of Laravel `make:auth` to be able to add some roles like `isEmployee` and/or `isCustomer`.

How can I achieve this using the available option I have? 
I hope, I somewhat explained my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Having a column `is_admin` is targeted to only one role. This tells you if user is an admin or not.

I would suggest you to change depending on any of below cases :

**1. If user can have just 1 role :**

Modify `users` table and change `is_admin` to `role`. Inside `role` column, you can store the role of that particular user like `admin`, `employee`, 'customer` etc.

**2. If user has multiple roles(many-to-many) :**

Remove column `is_admin` from `users` table and create a new table `role_user` which will have `user_id` and `role_id`. You will need to have another table called `roles` to store all available roles in your system.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I get what you're trying to say. However, in Laravel there are built-in functionalities related to the `make:auth` command such as if the user is is_admin and when logged in redirect to `some page`, this is just one example of them. If I modified the `column`, I am thinking that there are so many changes that I need to do in codes. Right? What do you suggest?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, Laravel does have `id, name, email, password,remember_token, created_at, updated_at` but `is_admin` seems to be added either manually or by some package installed later? See [this](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php)